# fullcalendar change column background color

Tags: fullcalendar

I am facing an issue with fullcalendar, I am trying to change the color of complete column of specific dates. I have tried this, but it's changing on only day cell color, I want to change complete column color of that specific date

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
var today = moment('2018-12-28T00:00Z');
        if (date.isSame(today, "day")) {
                cell.css("background", "#EEEEEE");
                //cell.addClass('fc-selectable-false'); 
            }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rendering property for event object to "background",
something like this,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultDate: '2018-11-10',
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  events: [
    {
      start: '2018-12-10T10:00:00',
      end: '2018-12-10T16:00:00',
      rendering: 'background'
    }
  ]
});
```

for more information please see fullcalendar documentation: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events